# How to delete database that does not exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i **tried** to create multiple rails app . I just deleted the file doing  *rm -rf* . Now when im trying to create a new rails app with the same and do db:create , it tells me that ex: "blog_development" already exist . How can i delete the database that i created that i just deleted the directory but didn't drop the database ? .

I tried this in other rails app directory ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:table_name) but it says the blog_development does not exist

Comment: try `rails db:reset`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in your DB console. For example, if you're using mysql:

Login to Mysql: `mysql -u <username> -p`

Delete the DB: `DROP DATABASE <db_name>`

Or you can just skip creating the database in your new app and just go straight to `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Thank you . I am able to find the blog_development in table plus and successfully drop the database from there . I thought if you remove the directory , the database will also be removed .  Is there anyway for me to see the list of database that i created  even I already deleted the directory ??  Im using VS code and postgresql in table plus

Comment: @eleazarlorea install [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/) to have access to the database server through a GUI